# Convert Date Formatting Codes to date

Tags: c#, date, date-formatting

The user is supposed to enter date in format: `%m %d %Y`

What I need to do is convert the date to: `11 11 2013` ( which is today`s date). I have not worked much with dates. Is there some method that does this conversion out of the box? I looked through DateTime options but couldn't find what I need.

Edit:

From the answers received it seems that it is not very clear what I am asking.

In our software the user can insert dates in format like this:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/date_variable_formatting.html

I am trying to parse this user input and return the today date. So from the link above:

%m   -  month - “01” to “12”

%d   -  day of the month, 2 digits with leading zeros - “01” to “31”

%Y  -   year, 4 digits -    “1999”

I was wondering if there is a method that takes `%m %d %Y` as an input and returns the corresponding today date in the specified format ( which is `11 11 2013` today). Or at least something close to that.
Hope it is more clear now.

EDIT 2:

After digging a little bit more I found that what I am looking for is an equivalent of C++ strftime in C#.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/

But for some reason I cannot see an example this to implemented in C#.

Comment: What means the percent sign?

Comment: I'm a bit confused on what you are after here. Are you having trouble parsing their date? Are you having trouble outputting yours? The input and output dates look like they are (or could be) the same format. Or do you want to convert to `dd MM yyyy` format? 11th November is not really a good date to use for demonstrating the desired date format...

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear. Do you just want to output TODAY's date in a dynamically-determined format?

Comment: Give us some psuedocode of what's being input/output. That will help a lot in solving your issue; it's just really unclear what you want.

Comment: String.Format() really seems like your best bet here. I see edit 2 now, and it still seems this is your best answer.

Comment: Mdb, did you find a way to do this. I am exactly on the same spot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My go-tos for DateTime Input and Output:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetime-parse for input (parsing)

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/ for output (formatting)

```
string dateString = "01 01 1992";
string format = "MM dd yyyy";

DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Edit since his edit makes my above answer irrelevant (but will leave there for reference):

From what you're saying, you want to output today's date in a dynamically-defined format?

So if I want to see month, date, year, I say "MM dd YY" and you return it to me?

If so:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today; // or initialize it as before, with the parsing (but just a regular DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse() or something quite similar)
```

Then

```
String formatString = "MM dd YY";
String.Format("{0:"+ formatString+"}", dt);
```

Your question is still quite unclear, though.

Comment: [Answers containing just a link are not very useful.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/130186)

Comment: Realized that after I posted it. Added a bit of explanation; that was bad of me to just post a link. Specifically, look at the parsing link! That really should be all you need.

Comment: It is not a link only answer. It is a answer like: If you really had googled before, you would have found THIS. I find this useful to new stackers for learn to google first.

Comment: @statue: I think the point is that you shouldn't be saying "Look at the parsing link" at all because all the necessary information should be in your answer. The links should be additional information (eg how to do it on other date formats) or just source references.

Comment: @nabuchodonossor: that is also not an answer. An answer should contain the information necessary to answer the question, not a way of finding that information. The reason links are bad is because if the websites die, are restructured, etc. then the answer becomes useless.

Comment: That totally makes sense. I think it's best to provide both the link AND the solution! ;) My answer and others combined should give that effect.

Comment: @statue: indeed. I wish others had had more links to the pages (though my preferred are the MSDN documentation). Edit your answer to make it stand alone though by adding in a relevant code snippet or something and your answer will become a thousand times better (and may well lose the downvotes).

Comment: I will go with mapping this format to C# equivalent. So for example '%b' goes to 'MMM'. And then string format it. Your answer is somewhere near to what I will do, so I will accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues with it. I could help more, I just don't exactly understand the question unfortunately. Feel free to PM.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` to parse a string to date and `DateTime-ToString` to convert it back to string with your desired format:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact("11 11 2013", "MM dd yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{ 
    // parsed successfully, parsedDate is initialized
    string result = parsedDate.ToString("MM dd yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    Console.Write(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("9 1 2009", "M d yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```