# DateTime: convert strftime format to c# format

Tags: c#, python, datetime, format, strftime

I am writing an application in `C#`. I have a `DateTime` object which I need to output in a format specified by customer input. The problem is that the format string that the user provides is not in `c#` jargon, the user is entering the strftime format `(i.e.:%Y %m %d)` , so I need to convert that to `c#` format. In this particular example the `c#` format for `"%Y %m %d"` will be `"yyyy MM dd"` .So before I write my own parser, isn't there already any function that will help map these two formats?

[strftime datetime formats](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/) vs [c# date time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

I have seen this question asked before, but people did not understand what the question was ([Convert Date Formatting Codes to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908063/convert-date-formatting-codes-to-date)), so fingers cross!

Many thanks

Comment: *strftime* is supported in c++, but not in c#. This is a UNIX format. I am also looking for this parser. Past 7 years and nothing.